# Import LinkedIn Publications on the site

Tags: api, web-scraping, linkedin-api, social-networking, data-import

I need to get last news/publications of company and import them to company separate site on page News. How can i get it work? 
I already have APi Key for it. 
I am looking here https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-shares# where describes how to get company publications. I try to get it by link `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{company_id}/updates~?oauth2_access_token={api_token}`
but get message

```
<error>
   <status>401</status>
   ...
   <error-code>0</error-code>
   <message>ssl required</message>
</error>
```

Now i didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 401 response is usually "access forbidden" Did you go over the explanation of linkedin [Oauth](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) and verified you are accessing accordingly? I don't think that would work with just hitting the url.. ypu should access with your  , pass all the needed data, etc. Good luck